# Php Javascript, a script is getting called on form submit

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Immigration,studytour,studyabroad,stemcourse">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />
    <title>Contact us &#8211; IVS Solutions</title>

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/responsive.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/demo.css">

    <!-- COLORS | CURRENTLY USED DIFFERENTLY TO SWITCH FOR DEMO. IN ORIGINAL FILE ALL COLORS AVAILABLE IN COLORS FOLDER -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/colors/default.css" title="default">
    <link rel="alternate stylesheet" href="assets/css/colors/default1.css" title="default1">
    <link rel="alternate stylesheet" href="assets/css/colors/default2.css" title="default2">
    <link rel="alternate stylesheet" href="assets/css/colors/default3.css" title="default3">
    <link rel="alternate stylesheet" href="assets/css/colors/default4.css" title="default4">
    <link rel="alternate stylesheet" href="assets/css/colors/default5.css" title="default5">
    <link rel="alternate stylesheet" href="assets/css/colors/default6.css" title="default6">
    <link rel="alternate stylesheet" href="assets/css/colors/default7.css" title="default7">
    <link rel="alternate stylesheet" href="assets/css/colors/default8.css" title="default8">
    <link rel="alternate stylesheet" href="assets/css/colors/default9.css" title="default9">
    <link rel="alternate stylesheet" href="assets/css/colors/default10.css" title="default10">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <?php require('constant.php') ?>
</head>

<body class="gray-bg">

    <!-- Start: Preloader
    ============================= -->

    <?php include 'top.php'; ?>

    <!-- Navigation End -->

    <!-- Breadcrumb Area -->
    <section id="breadcrumb-area" style="background-image: url(assets/img/contact-bg.jpg);">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 text-center">
                    <h1>Contact Us</h1>
                    <ul class="breadcrumb-nav list-inline">
                        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="active">Contact Us</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    </header>
    <!-- End: Header
    ============================= -->

    <!-- End: Contact Us Office
    ============================= -->

    <!-- Start: Contact Us
    ============================= -->
    <section id="contact-area">
        <div class="contact-box">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-12 rubal-bg ">
                    <div class="contact-us-info ">
                        <h3>Contact Us</h3>
                      
                        <a href="#" class="live-chat boxed-btn rubal-btn-modal" data-toggle="modal"
                            data-target="#myModal"><i class="fa fa-book"></i> Ask a Counselor</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-12" style="background-color: #fff !important;">
                    <div class="get-in-touch">
                        <h3>Get in Touch</h3>
                        <p>If you need any assistance Please feel free to contact us.</p>
                        <!-- <form role="form" method="post" class="leave-reply-form style-2" id="" action="https://getform.io/f/9ccd51bb-0b03-45be-9137-968b8506f340"> -->
                        <form role="form" method="post" class="leave-reply-form style-2" id="contact-form"
                            action="forms/contactus.php" novalidate="novalidate">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="form-group has-error has-danger">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Name*" class="form-control" name="name"
                                            id="name" data-error="Name field is required" required="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="form-group has-error has-danger">
                                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email*" class="form-control" name="email"
                                            id="email" data-error="Email field is required" required="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="form-group has-error has-danger">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile No.*" class="form-control" name="phone"
                                            id="phone" data-error="Mobile No. field is required" required="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="form-group has-error has-danger">
                                        <input type="text" placeholder="Preferred Country for Education*"
                                            class="form-control" name="country" id="country"
                                            data-error="Country field is required" required="">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="form-group has-error has-danger">
                                        <select name="lookingfor" id="lookingfor" class="form-control"
                                            data-error="Looking for field is required" required="">
                                            <option selected disabled>Looking For*</option>
                                            <option value="Post Graduate Program">Post Graduate Program</option>
                                            <option value="Graduate Program">Graduate Program</option>
                                            <option value="Research Program">Research Program</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Example reCAPTCHA widget -->
                                <div class="g-recaptcha col-sm-12" data-sitekey="<?php echo SITE_KEY ?>"></div>
                                <!-- Error message container for reCAPTCHA -->
                                <div id="recaptcha-error"></div>
                                <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="form-group margin-bottom-none">
                                        <button type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="submit"
                                            class="btn btn-brand submit-btn form-btn"
                                            style="width: 100%;color: #000;background-color: #fdc800;cursor:pointer;">Submit</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-sm-12">
                                    <div class="form-response"></div>
                                </div>
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- End: Contact Us
    ============================= -->

    <!-- Start: Footer Sidebar
    ============================= -->



    <?php include 'footer.php'; ?>


    
    <!-- End: Footer Copyright
    ============================= -->
    
    
    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script data-cfasync="false" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/5c5dd728/cloudflare-static/email-decode.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.meanmenu.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.counterup.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.shuffle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/wow.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Smooth Scroll -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/latest/plugins/ScrollToPlugin.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Map Script -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAqoWGSQYygV-G1P5tVrj-dM2rVHR5wOGY"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/map-script.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Script -->
    <script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
    <?php include('footer-script.php'); ?>

    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
    <script>
        // Validate the form and reCAPTCHA response before submission
        document.getElementById('contact-form').addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
            alert("script called");
            console.log(grecaptcha)
            var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
            if (response.length === 0) {
                event.preventDefault(); // Prevent form submission
                document.getElementById('recaptcha-error').innerHTML = 'Please complete the reCAPTCHA.';
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

this is the code, i am trying to disallow form to get submitted when captcha is not completed, with the script but the script is not getting called at all, i tried adding console log and alert to check the same but it is not getting displayed.

script should be called and form should not be submitted without captcha being completely.

Comment: i just created the captcha keys on google console, added it in the code like shown in the code, created the given script

Comment: The code seems to be correct. However, there are a few things you can check:

Make sure the Google reCAPTCHA script is loaded correctly. 

Check that the grecaptcha object is available in the global scope. You can add a console.log(grecaptcha) statement before your event listener to verify this.

Ensure that the form element with the id contact-form exists in the HTML. Double-check any typos or missing elements.

Comment: on doing  console.log(grecaptcha), i get contact-us-cap-2.php:579 Uncaught ReferenceError: grecaptcha is not defined
    at contact-us-cap-2.php:579:21 error. how do i add it to globa scope?

Comment: It should be global anyway. As its source script loads asynchronously, it's possible it's not defined before you try to log it. Try logging it inside the event listener instead.

Comment: Also, do you actually see the catpcha displayed on the page correctly? Does the Network tool show that the `api.js` loaded correctly?

Comment: i can see the captcha on the screen and works fine but even if i dont ckeck the captcha form gets submitted

Comment: @VinaySavla It doesn't I don't think...I tested that myself (using your code in a JSFiddle). Your code will prevent form submission, assuming the response.length is actually 0 in the real case - have you double-checked what `response` actually contains, when you are debugging? I also wonder if maybe you have another JS error in your page which is preventing scripts from running. There might be a console error about it, perhaps. I'm not sure that what you've posted is actually a [mre] of the issue.

Comment: i tried adding it inside event listner but the problem is that event listner function is either not called ot not working

Comment: i can see this error in console log
[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See <URL>

Comment: As I said, I tested your code and the event listener is working. Here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/hoL7csug/ . Even though the recaptcha site key is not valid, it is running the event listener and logging the expected values, and preventing the form from being submitted.

Comment: What URL does that error message tell you to look at? There are some [interesting results](https://www.google.com/search?q=%5BIntervention%5D+Unable+to+preventDefault+inside+passive+event+listener+due+to+target+being+treated+as+passive) for that error message. Are you using some sort of framework on your page? As I said before, we will need to see a [mre] of the issue before we can help you and be sure how to fix your problem. See also [ask]. You should always ensure that the code you post will actually show the problem, before you post it. Now you will need to [edit] it to make that happen.

Comment: i have posted the complete code. if that helps you'll figure out the error i am facing

Comment: Can you answer my questions too please? Also I don't want your entire code, much of which almost certainly isn't relevant. I asked for a [mre] of the issue, as per Stackoverflow's [ask] guidance. That involves you giving it some thought and working out which parts of your page are actually needed to be shown in order for the error to occur when the code is run. That process in itself can often help you to pinpoint the error yourself too. Also I don't know what's in half of those linked script files, so it would be very difficult to predict what the code will do when they are all present.

Comment: A good experiment (and a big step towards a [mre]) would be to see if the problem goes away when you make a new page with only the form and the recaptcha code in it, without any of the other stuff. Then add other scripts and elements back in again, one at a time, until the problem starts to re-occur. That will help you, and us, to narrow down the issue.

Comment: i'll do that and update it again

Comment: i got the sololution, thank you, the issue was top.php that was included also had contact-form id

Comment: Well done. That hopefully shows you the benefit of trying to create the minimal example. It's a really good debugging tool! It sounds like we can just close the post now, as it was a simple naming clash.

Answer (score -3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Head content -->
</head>
<body class="gray-bg">
    <!-- HTML code for the contact form -->
    <form role="form" method="post" class="leave-reply-form style-2" id="contact-form" action="forms/contactus.php">
        <!-- Form fields -->
        <!-- Example reCAPTCHA widget -->
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="YOUR_SITE_KEY"></div>
        <!-- Error message container for reCAPTCHA -->
        <div id="recaptcha-error"></div>

        <!-- Change the  button type to `button` and add an `ID` to capture click event -->
        <button type="button" id="contact-form-btn" class="btn btn-brand submit-btn form-btn" style="width: 100%; color: #000; background-color: #fdc800; cursor:pointer;">Submit</button>
    </form>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
    <script>
        // Validate the form and reCAPTCHA response before submission
        document.getElementById('contact-form-btn').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            
            var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
            if (response.length === 0) {
                document.getElementById('recaptcha-error').innerHTML = 'Please complete the reCAPTCHA.';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('contact-form').submit();
            }
        });
    </script>
    <!-- Other HTML and scripts -->
</body>
</html>
```

What I have done is mentioned below :

1. Change the button type in the form to `button`.
2. Add a new attribute `id` to the button.
3. Change the `id` inside `getElementById` from `contact-form` to `contact-form-btn`.
4. Changed the event registration from `submit` to `click`.
5. Added `else` block inside the javascript which will submit the form if captcha is valid.

*NOTE: You have to check thoroughly the response you are getting in the line `var response = grecaptcha.getResponse();` and verify it in line `if (response.length === 0) {`.*

Comment: Please read this [reCAPTCHA v3](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3#site_verify_response) documentation for better options.

Comment: Why have you done these steps? There doesn't appear to be any meaningful change. You're simply handling the submit event differently. But handling the submit event wasn't the problem before...that part was already working (I tested it myself). Your answer lists what you've done, but doesn't explain why you think it solves the problem in the question.